# Can be bad for SEO to submit links in Google disavow tools?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, disavow-links

I have a website & I found some spammy inbound links. I have collected these links & submitted them to the Google Disavow tool.  Day by day I now see Google Search Console reducing them. I am also seeing some of my keywords rank drop.

Is it possible that disavowing links had a bad effect on SEO for my site?

Comment: The disavow link should be used only in extreme cases. Otherwise, Google  knows spammy links and sites and will mostly ignore junk links. Google does warn about using this tool.

Comment: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2648487?hl=en  "[the disavow links tool] should only be used with caution. If used incorrectly, this feature can potentially harm your site’s performance in Google’s search results. We recommend that you disavow backlinks only if you believe you have a considerable number of spammy, artificial, or low-quality links pointing to your site, and if you are confident that the links are causing issues for you. In most cases, Google can assess which links to trust without additional guidance, so most normal or typical sites will not need to use this tool.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller *...this feature can potentially harm your site’s performance...* Don't I know it! I blocked one sites links and my stats went into the toilet. I was doing okay and then got pinged. Sometimes this can make the difference between being penalized or not since links and link value can effect how a site is seen. This assumes a site is on the edge of course. Reducing the links even from spam sites can teeter a sites quality scores from poor to downright sucky wucky woo. (official terminology)